# Need some help finding where my Next without For error is coming from

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set xlCell = Range("A2")
    For index = 1 To i
        'update values in the status column
        If xlCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = "True" Then
            xlCell.Value = ""
        ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value < Date Then 'Done and overdue tasks
            If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                If xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value > wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(25, 3).Value Then
                    xlCell.Value = "Done"
                End If
            ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value < 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Overdue"
            End If
        ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value < wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(25, 4).Value Then 'Doing this week tasks
            If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Done"
            Else
                xlCell.Value = "To be completed this week"
            End If
        ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value < wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(25, 5).Value Then 'to be done next week
            If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Done"
            Else
                xlCell.Value = "To complete next week"
            End If
        ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 6).Value < Date And xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value > wb.Worksheets("DashBoard").Cells(25, 4).Value And xlCell.Offset(0, 4).Value <= (Counter / xlCell.Offset(0, 3)) * 100 / 0.75 Then
            If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Done"
            Else
                xlCell.Value = "Off Track"
            End If
        ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 6).Value < Date And xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value > wb.Worksheets("DashBoard").Cells(25, 4).Value And (Counter / xlCell.Offset(0, 3)) * 100 / 0.75 < xlCell.Offset(0, 4) <= Counter / xlCell.Offset(0, 3) * 100 Then
            If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Done"
            Else
                xlCell.Value = "At Risk"
        End If
        'Hide rows not required
        If xlCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = "True" Then
           If xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value < wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(25, 3).Value Then
                If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                    xlCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 6).Value > wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(25, 5).Value Then
                xlCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        ElseIf xlCell.Value = "" Then
            xlCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        Set xlCell = xlCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next index
```

Comment: You are missing an End If in the last Else IF in the first long If statement.

Comment: You are missing an `end if` here:   `If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
                xlCell.Value = "Done"
            Else
                xlCell.Value = "At Risk"`

Comment: I like how all three of us are on this LOL

Comment: If I don't rush to answer the easy ones, then I don't know if I'd answer any. :)

Comment: @MattCremeens Exactly!

Comment: @MattCremeens sadly i have to take whatever low hanging fruit i can get O_o

Comment: Thanks guys, such a rookie error on my part!

Comment: Also, a small note, I see you may be using multiple worksheets. Your very first `Range("A1")` should have the workbook and worksheet you expect that value to come from, just to be explicit with the code. ie `Set xlCell = wb.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre missing an end if here

```
    ElseIf xlCell.Offset(0, 6).Value < Date And xlCell.Offset(0, 7).Value > wb.Worksheets("DashBoard").Cells(25, 4).Value And (Counter / xlCell.Offset(0, 3)) * 100 / 0.75 < xlCell.Offset(0, 4) <= Counter / xlCell.Offset(0, 3) * 100 Then
        If xlCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = 100 Then
            xlCell.Value = "Done"
        Else
            xlCell.Value = "At Risk"
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I need a break, always useful having a second pair of eyes to check over things :)

Comment: @FrasercT help a guy out with a check mark and a mark up :D